# Get Laravel Command output to web page

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I am trying to debug a particularly nasty nested array of information and dealing with about 7 levels of foreach loops in an Artisan Command. Normally while designing this I would fire up the browser to do a nice pretty print of the arrays with collapsing tree view.

With Artisan commands, when running it from the console it just dumps so much info it isn't useful. I am not sure if that is possible but thought I would ask. I tried just copying the code to a tempCommand.php in the public path, but then it can't find any of the other namespaces like App/User

Answer (score 0):

There is [this package](https://github.com/nunomaduro/collision) designed to give you beautiful error reporting when interacting with your app through the command line. You can import it to your project.

Alternatively, you can upgrade to `Laravel 5.6` which is shipped with the mentioned package by default.